# Unable to Print value from Activity to fragment in android

Tags: android

In method `onButtonClick` in Activity I am calling this:

```
Button sucessbutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.sucessbutton);
sucessbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    startActivityForResult(returnIntent, 0);
    finish();
  }
});
```

In my Fragment we are going back and calling:

```
@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
  super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
  if (requestCode == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

But I am unable to print OK value when I am coming back from Activity to Fragment. When I click on button I am getting this exception:

Error Log:

```
info.androidhive.materialdesign, PID: 15748
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {  }
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1765)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3821)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3782)
            at info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.RemarksList$8.onClick(RemarksList.java:851)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19769)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Please tell me where am doing wrong :

Answer (score 0):

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { }

Due to this line :

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
```

Not specifying any action or Activity which want to start on Click of Button.

if want to start a `Activity` then prepare intent as:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),<ACTIVITY_NAME.class>);
```

Comment: what action we have to perform here

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment: why you are using `startActivityForResult` ?

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment: in your code problem is caused by `Intent returnIntent = new Intent();startActivityForResult(returnIntent, 0);` . and we are unable to tell you right solution until you are not telling why you have added these lines on button click

Comment: coz i want to finish it and go from current actvity to fragment  and reload and refresh listview or reloadfragment

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment : then remove `Intent returnIntent = new Intent();startActivityForResult(returnIntent, 0);` lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94162/discussion-between-research-development-and--k).